# NameError: uninitialized constant FILTER

Tags: filter, initialization, hbase, constants, nameerror

How to configure Filters on HBase?

```
hbase(main):005:0> scan 'List', {
   COLUMNS => 'Attributes:supplierPartNumber', 
   FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('Attributes'), 
   Bytes.toBytes('supplierPartNumber'), 
   CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), 
   Bytes.toBytes('00980866000P'))"
}
```

> NameError: uninitialized constant FILTER

Answer (score 0):

First import the all these filters packages then funt he filter command. I think this will help you

```
hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.BinaryComparator;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter. Filter;
```